# Column being pushed down using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, position

I am having an issue withe bootstrap I am using. For some reason the third column is being pushed down. I have no idea why. I am totally stuck on this issue, it is only happening on this page for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
</div> 
  <div class="profit col-md-4 align-center">
    <img src="images/profit.png">
    <div class="rmo">
    <p>Ready Made Arch Support</p>
    </div>
        <div class="prof">
        <p>We stock over 75 sizes, 6 times more than other stores do. This is our most basic orthotic offered. Available for you to take home on the same day as your visit. We will fit you!</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="select col-md-4 align-center">
    <img src="images/select.png">
    <div class="cso">
    <p>Custom Select Orthotic</p>
    </div>
        <div class="sel">
            <p>We have an exclusive method of building custom orthotics without the high cost of traditional plaster casting. All of our orthotics are made local and come with a 24-48hr turn around.</p>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="cast col-md-4 align-center">
    <img src="images/cast.png">
    <div class="cco">
    <p>Custom Cast Orthotics</p>
    </div>
        <div class="cas">
            <p>For patients that need precise correction or complex offloading we offer custom cast orthotics that are created to address your specific needs. Available for pick up within 48 hrs.</p>
        </div>
.rmo{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold; 
}

.cso{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Comment: A bit of advice, right click your element and click `Inspect element` then take a look at the `DOM` tree. Try and change some CSS rules in the `Styles section` of the developer tools interface for your element or the other elements that you suspect may be causing the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class ".cast" is using positioning of left 535px and top 425px which is forcing it down.

With Bootstrap it's important to place all column definitions within a row class and that within a container to help ensure proper padding, margins and clearing. When I place the col definitions into a class row and removed that position everything lined up.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="profit col-md-4 align-center">
            <img src="images/profit.png">
            <div class="rmo">
                <p>Ready Made Arch Support</p>
            </div>
            <div class="prof">
                <p>We stock over 75 sizes, 6 times more than other stores do. This is our most basic orthotic offered. Available for you to take home on the same day as your visit. We will fit you!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="select col-md-4 align-center">
            <img src="images/select.png">
            <div class="cso">
                <p>Custom Select Orthotic</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sel">
                <p>We have an exclusive method of building custom orthotics without the high cost of traditional plaster casting. All of our orthotics are made local and come with a 24-48hr turn around.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cast col-md-4 align-center">
            <img src="images/cast.png">
            <div class="cco">
                <p>Custom Cast Orthotics</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cas">
                <p>For patients that need precise correction or complex offloading we offer custom cast orthotics that are created to address your specific needs. Available for pick up within 48 hrs.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate that. I did not realize that I used the same class for two different pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your own CSS contains:

```
.cast {
    position: absolute;
    left: 535px; 
    top: 425px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;    
}
```

So your third div is being absolutely positioned.  F12 is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

The div are outside of the container, you should use the col-* with a row to be sure they are aligned in the same line. Your code will look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```